# Get unread gmail mails with imap

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

Hello I'm trying to iplement some basics Google Api features and I get some issues when I try to get the unread messages in the gmail mailbox. Here is my code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const Imap = require('imap');

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL
const REFRESH_TOKEN = process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN

const oauht2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI)
oauht2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token : REFRESH_TOKEN})

function newMessages(/*onNewEmailCallback*/) {
    const imap = new Imap({
        user: "mymail@gmail.com",
        xoauth2: oauht2Client.getAccessToken(),
        host: 'imap.gmail.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
        tlsOptions: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
    function showError(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }

    function showMessage(msg) {
        onNewEmailCallback(msg.subject);
        console.log(msg.subject);
    }

    imap.connect();
    
    imap.once('ready', () => {
        imap.openBox('INBOX', true, (err, box) => {
            if (err) showError(err);
            imap.on('mail', (numNewMsgs) => {
                imap.search(['UNSEEN'], (err, results) => {
                    if (err) showError(err);
                    results.forEach((result) => {
                        const f = imap.fetch(result, { bodies: '' });
                        f.on('message', (msg) => {
                            msg.on('body', (stream, info) => {
                                let buffer = '';
                                stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                                    buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
                                });
                                stream.on('end', () => {
                                    showMessage(Imap.parseHeader(buffer));
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

    imap.once('error', showError);
    imap.once('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection terminée');
    });
    return imap;
}
```

When I call it in the index.js I get the error

```
/home/.../node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1804 
    return str.replace(RE_BACKSLASH, '\\\\').replace(RE_DBLQUOTE, '\\"');
             ^

 TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at escape
```

I'm probably passing a bad argument during the imap connection but I don't really know which one and I don't find anything online. Help PLEASE

By the way I had a certificate issue that's why I add the tlsOptions property.
Here the full traceback of the error:

```
/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-segnon.gnonlonfoun/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1804
  return str.replace(RE_BACKSLASH, '\\\\').replace(RE_DBLQUOTE, '\\"');
             ^

TypeError: str.replace is not a function
    at escape (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1804:14)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1672:24)
    at Connection._resTagged (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1535:22)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10)
    at Parser.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at Parser._resTagged (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:175:10)
    at Parser._parse (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:139:16)
    at Parser._tryread (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:82:15)
    at Parser._cbReadable (/home/lerou/B-DEV-500-COT-5-2-area-/Back-End/node_modules/imap/lib/Parser.js:53:12)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28)
```

Comment: can we see the full traceback of the error?

Comment: I add the full traceback